# Incidental programming language aesthetics - smiley face

Tags: esoteric-languages

Is there a programming language where `:)` is valid syntax (excluding custom defined templates or operator overloading etc)?

Comment: Something like this? http://xkcd.com/541/

Comment: Totally unrelated to the question, but I highly approve of your username.

Comment: YEAH! Someone else understands me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Matlab.  `a(:)` means "all the elements of `a` arranged as a column vector".  Given liberal whitespace, you could also write it as `a( :)`.

Comment: Well - I guess that is a correct answer. I wonder if anyone can find a language for which it works without "liberal whitespace"